# Postico, showing tables while doing query at the same time

Tags: postico

> [image]

I'm trying to show the table while I'm doing querying so I can see what I'm doing, does anyone know how to show the table?

Another question is, does anyone who knows sql mind helping me with misc questions? I have lots of bits of questions that I would like to ask which may not be appropriate for forums.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Postico license you can have multiple tabs and windows open at the same time. I'm not sure if that answers all of your concerns, but I hope that helps.